# How could I get ID of html tag in the onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I generate a list which elements have the id with their real database ID. I want to get that Id to give it to the onclick function (function is "eliminaComentario(id)"). The html is generated by javascript string like this:

```
mensaje = "<div id =\"comentario-"+listaMensajes[i].id+"\"><output style=\"color: #d17b12;\">"+listaMensajes[i].emisor+" - "+listaMensajes[i].fecha+"</output><br>" +
                                "<output id='idComentario-"+listaMensajes[i].id+"' name='nombreComentario-"+listaMensajes[i].id+"'>"
                                +"<textarea readonly rows='3' cols='200' style='border: 1;'>"+listaMensajes[i].mensaje+"</textarea></output><br>" +
                                        "<a id =\"eliminaComentario-"+listaMensajes[i].id+"\" href=\"\" style=\"color: red; font-size: 8px; text-align: right;\" onclick=\"eliminaComentario(**///ID OF THIS LINK//**);\">Eliminar</a><br></div>";
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `this.id` ...

Comment: this should work:
`onclick=\"eliminaComentario("+listaMensajes[i].id+");\"`

Comment: hahaha, oh god, my mind... i was trying to get it after create when i can get it before create... You are right. Thanks.